# Looping through a Python pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table that I have created (pivotTable) using:

```
pivotTable= dayData.pivot_table(index=['sector'], aggfunc='count')
```

which has produced the following pivot table:

```
                   sector id  
broad_sector                            
Communications         2   2 
Utilities              3   3
Media                  3   3
```

Is there a way to loop through the pivot table assigning the index value and sector total to respective variables `sectorName` and `sectorCount`?

I have tried:

```
i=0
while i <= lenPivotTable:
    sectorName = sectorPivot.index.get_level_values(0)
    sectorNumber = sectorPivot.index.get_level_values(1)
    i=i+1
```

to return for the first loop iteration:

```
sectorName = 'Communications'
sectorCount = 2
```

for the second loop iteration:

```
sectorName = 'Utilities'
sectorCount = 3
```

for the third loop iteration:

```
sectorName = 'Media'
sectorCount = 3
```

But can't get it to work.

Comment: It's not clear what are you going to achieve. Could you post a desired result set?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. This is a guide on [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why do you need this (because looping through DF is **very** slow), but you can do it this way:

```
In [403]: for idx, row in pivotTable.iterrows():
   .....:         sectorName = idx
   .....:         sectorCount = row['sector']
   .....:         print(sectorName, sectorCount)
   .....:


Communications 2
Utilities 3
Media 3
```

Comment: Many thanks, I'm still learning so this will help me understand the basics before moving on

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will get you the values as asked.

```
for sector_name, sector_count, _ in pivotTable.to_records():
    print(sector_name, sector_count)
```